# How to prepend a word with a letter if the first letter of that word is upper-case?

Tags: c#, string, cpu-word, uppercase

If i have for example this `String`:

```
String paragraphWord = "This is A String of WoRDs";
```

This is my desired result:

**k**This is **k**A **K**String of **k**WorDS

So i want to add **k** before every word which first letter is upper-case. How to do that?

This is what i've tried without success:

```
String paragraphWord = "This is A String of WoRDs";
String replacewords = string.Concat(paragraphWord.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c) ? "k" + c.ToString() : c.ToString())).TrimStart();
```

The (incorrect) result is: `kThis is kA kString of kWokRkDs`

Comment: "I want" is not a question.

Comment: Use a regex perhaps? You seem to have left out the part with what you've tried.

Comment: `string.Concat("String of Words".Select(x => Char.IsUpper(x) ? "I copied my homework" + x : x.ToString()));`

Comment: Also, what happened to the `R` in your example? It was uppercase in your input but lowercase in your output.

Comment: Why is the `K` before `String` the only uppercase `k`?

Comment: Sorry with all, I made a mistake. I don't put what already I had done This is my code String replacewords = string.Concat(WordString.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c)? "k" + c.ToString() : c.ToString())).TrimStart(); But this did not work I got this result "KReplace kWokRkDs" and I wanted "KReplace kWoRDs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
string paragraphWord = "This is A String of WoRDs";
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<=^|\W)([A-Z])");
Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(paragraphWord,"k$1"));
```

Explaining `(?<=^|\W)([A-Z])`

```
?<=     positive look behind
^|\W    start of the string or a whitespace character
[A-Z]   A single upper case letter
```

So we are looking for a single upper case letter proceeded by either the start of the string or a space. We group that character so we can use it in our replacement:

```
k$1
```

subs our match with `k` and the match group `$1`

Answer (score 1):

```
String kWords = string.Join(" ", "This is A String of WoRDs"
    .Split()
    .Select(w => Char.IsUpper(w[0]) ? "k" + w : w));
```

Comment: Can I ask why you feel questions as poor as this merit spoon-feeding an answer? I really don't think we should send the message we do people's homework for them.

Comment: @tnw: if it's homework i don't think that he can use LINQ. It didn't take that much time, maybe it's helpful for him or someone else.

Comment: Whether it's helpful is debatable as I doubt OP actually learns *anything* if they don't even have to think or try because someone just does it for them... plus I still think it encourages help vampires which are generally bad for the community.

Comment: I don't have experience with you. I'm new to programming, Thanks for your answer but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: @LorenaL: then you have to explain better what you need next time since the result is the same as your desired (apart from the lower`k` before `String`). You should also try something before you ask a question, otherwise people assume that you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @  Tim Schmelter Sorry. I made a mistake. I don't put what already  I had done 
This is my code             

String replacewords = string.Concat(WordString.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c)? "k" + c.ToString() : c.ToString())).TrimStart();
But this did not work
I got this result "KReplace kWokRkDs"  and I wanted "KReplace kWoRDs".

Comment: @LorenaL: i still don't understand what's wrong with my approch since it should do what you want. I guess you have overlooked that i'm splitting every word as opposed to your `String.Concat` approach which enumerates every character instead of every word.